# Passing id value to a variable not working, only returning itstrue

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I tried to add 2 field value and compare it with dropdown value with JS but its not working with variable.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#SAVE,#CREATE').mouseover(function(e) {

          var value89 = $('#P315_THRESHOLD').val() || 0;
           var value20 = parseFloat($('#P315_C_RELEASE_REQUEST').val()) || 0;
           var value21 = parseFloat($('#P315_O_RELEASE_REQUEST').val()) || 0;
           var valuetot3 = value20 + value21 ;
           var str = "";
               if( value89 = '>250' &&  valuetot3 < 250  )
                       {
           alert('CAPEX and OPEX request total value should be greater than 250 , current total is' +$('#P315_THRESHOLD').val() || 0);
                       }
        });
     });
```

Expected result is that it should throw alert for the conditions.

Comment: did you mean to check if `value89` is equal to or greater than 250? Then it should be `value89 >= 250`

Comment: Could you provide the html ?

Comment: Show us your error

Answer (score 1):

`if( value89 = '>250' &&  valuetot3 < 250  )`
........................^ this is an affectation instead of a comparaison
Either use `value89 === '>250'` or `value89 >= 250`

Answer (score 0):

This should work according to your condition. Just remove **= '>250'** and replace **>=250**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#SAVE,#CREATE').mouseover(function(e) {
       var value89 = $('#P315_THRESHOLD').val() || 0;
       var value20 = parseFloat($('#P315_C_RELEASE_REQUEST').val()) || 0;
       var value21 = parseFloat($('#P315_O_RELEASE_REQUEST').val()) || 0;
       var valuetot3 = value20 + value21 ;
       var str = "";

       if( value89 >=250 &&  valuetot3 < 250  ){
            alert('CAPEX and OPEX request total value should be greater than 250 , current total is' +$('#P315_THRESHOLD').val() || 0);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```